# odoo 16 create a link that opens in set company

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

what i am trying to do is create link that will open a set company. now when i create the url using base_url with a link to a record it tries to open in the current company and so gives an access error.

Thank you for your suggestions.

```
 def make_record_link(self, record='', action='', menu=''):
    link = ''
    record = record or self
    if record:
        ir_param = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo()
        base_url = ir_param.get_param('web.base.url')
        if base_url:
            base_url += '/web#&model=%s&id=%s' % (record._name,record.id)
        link = '<a href="'+base_url+'">'+record.name+'</a>'
    return str(link)
```

i added more information for context the function is base on the odoo code but i am not sure how to represent the company.

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you share your code.
Without it, I would just say that you need to add a `.with_company(company.id)`

Comment: @Levizar i added the function at the end i add this link to  an  email but i am not sure how to represent the company. the code i collected form odoo code